# How to multiple select in same table, in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a single query to multiple select, my purpose is to reduce mysql process, so I use this query, but it does not work:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM  `my_setting` 
 WHERE `setting` = `site_url` 
   AND `setting` = `site_name`
```

I use `select UNION` query, but I think it doesn't reduce memory.

Comment: use OR comparator instead of AND

Comment: Are you trying to select all rows where the 'setting' is either 'site_name" or 'site_url'? In such case, I think you'd want to have OR instead of AND. With AND, the query is returning no results because setting can't equal two different things.

Comment: Bohemian give me answer :) thanks... sorry I can't vote up, my reputation only 1. Thanks for all of you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you want either:

```
SELECT * FROM my_setting
WHERE `setting` in ('site_url', 'site_name')  -- if site_url is a literal string
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM my_setting
WHERE `setting` in (site_url, site_name) -- if site_url is a column name
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FORM `my_setting` WHERE (`setting` = `site_url` OR `setting` = `site_name`)
```

Should get you where you need to go.